# How to use a CSV as input data for a Tensorflow neural network?

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I'm currently attempting to write a neural network by slightly changing the [MNIST for ML Beginners code](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#mnist-for-ml-beginners). I have a CSV that's organized like this:

`Image_Name     |Nevus?  |Dysplastic Nevus?|  Melanoma?
asdfgjkgdsl.png |1       |0                |0`

An image name, and it's one-hot result. Each image is 1022 x 767, and I'd like to use the color of each pixel as an input as well. As such, I changed the MNIST code to have 2,351,622 inputs (1022 pixels wide * 767 pixels high * 3 colors per pixel) and 3 outputs.

```
# from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
# mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

def main():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2351622])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeroes([2351622, 3]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeroes([3]))

    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(1000):
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])
        # batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        # sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

The commented lines are the ones that I have to replace to get my data loaded into the neural network. The easiest way to get the 2.3M inputs for each image (that I've found) is to:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

list(np.array(Image.open('asdfgjkgdsl.png')).ravel().flatten())
```

How can I load this dataset into tensorflow to be used for training a neural network?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the recommended way is to prepare a series of `tf_records` files. There is an example in MNIST for doing that. Then, you create a queue. To save space, it's probably best to keep the input in the png format and use `decode_png` at runtime.

In short, first convert (you should write multiple files):

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def convert():
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_filename)
    for filename, nv, dnv, mn in parse_csv(...):
       fs = {}
       png_data = read_image_as_np_array(filename)
       image_name = 'data/image/png'
       fs['png_data'] = _bytes_feature(png_data)
       fs['label'] = _bytes_feature([nv, dnv, mn])
       example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=fs))
       writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
```

Then, read it: (put that in a queue)

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_from_queue)
features_def = {
  'png_data': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
  'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.uint8)
}
features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature_def)
image = tf.image.decode_png(features['png_data'])
...
```

You can also use [`tf.TextLineReader`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#TextLineReader) to read line by line instead.